# how to concatenate text & view model item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, string-concatenation

Hi I am trying to join two bits of information on an MVC view to create one long string on screen. I have a bit of text within  <\a> and a returned variable in the model (model.item.number).

Currently I have the following in my view :

a>01643< / a>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phone)

this returns the correct value, but gives a space between 01634 and the item.phone value. I have tried wrapping the whole thing with < a > but to no avail.

I am sure this is dead simple & so easy in webforms. can someone put me out of my misery and let me know how to do this.. I'm an MVC3 noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space:

```
a>01643</a>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phone)
```

Or, Just write the value:

```
a>01643< / a>@Html.DisplayText(Model.item.phone)
```